# Storybook.js adds commas to special characters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, storybook

I have this in JSX: `{'&ldquo;'}{this.props.text}{'&rdquo;'}` which produces this in the Storybook viewer: `“,Text here!,”` I need to figure out where the commas are coming from. How do I get rid of them or how can I figure out where they're coming from? Is this in a template somewhere? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the commas are between in inline JSX. Try a single JSX expression with the string concatenation inside like: `{'&ldquo;' + this.props.text + '&rdquo;'}`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that yesterday and Storybook complains about the plusses. I've found the solution and posted it below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, after working with one of my colleagues, here is the answer:

```js
{`&ldquo;${this.props.text}&rdquo;`}
```

This adds the interpolated text in between double quotes without commas.